# Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation - Get List items API - Postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, custom, microsoft-graph, azure-ad

I have just created an App in Azure Portal by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins-modernize/from-acs-to-aad-apps) Article.

I have followed the following Steps:

1. Registered App in Azure AD
2. Get the Client ID and Secret from the Registered App
3. Created API Permissions for the newly Created App in Azure Portal. have granted the following Permissions:

**Microsoft Graph**

Application permissions:

Sites.FullControl.All: Have full control of all site collections

**SharePoint**

Application permissions:

Sites.FullControl.All: Have full control of all site collections

4. Generated the Access Token by hitting the following API from PostMan

   https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/befcd140-15d5-4713-a86a-02fec98214ba/tokens/oAuth/2

The Access Token is generating Successfully but when I try to hit GetListItems API using PostMan, it returns following Exception:

```
   <m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.</m:message>
```

[image]

I have also added the following Permissions:

At this Page, https://engro2.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx , I retrieved App using Client ID then Added the following Permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">

<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />

</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Please Help me in resolving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Sites.Read.All permission on the SharePoint permissions blade. Full Control does not give you permission on list items.

Also they'll need to be Application permissions, not delegated.

The Graph and AppInv permissions, you do not need them.

Comment: Granted. still same